# Azure Alert(Monitor) for CosmosDB doesn't fire for requests with StatusCode 429 dimension filter

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-monitoring

I am unable to fire an Azure Alert having StatusCode Dimension set to 429 ([Azure Alert Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeTkN.png)) while in Metrics [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45aP4.png) shows that there are such type of requests.

Comment: You might need to reach out to Azure Support or AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com to figure this out.

Comment: Can you show the time range and interval of the alert?

Comment: I have tried with following options: 1) Period - over last 1 minutes; Frequency - every 1 minute; 2) Period - over last 5 minutes; Frequency - every 1 minute

Comment: Which metric did you select when creating the condition? "Total requests" do the trick for me

Comment: Did you check-mark the box 'Select' next to the 'StatusCode'?
There's the instruction that says "If you do not select any value for a dimension, that dimension will be ignored."

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there was a bug in Azure Alert. The problem was fixed by contacting their support.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? What exactly was the response and action done by the support?

Comment: This is the response from the support: "The product team has said that have done some backend fix into your account and its okay to fire the alerts on database level or database account level."